# Two linear layouts in the same line. The first must fill all remaining space

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to put 2 linear layouts in the same line. The second layout of fixed with, but the first must fill all remaining space. In the code below I have marked my changes. But I don´t know how to make the second layout of fixed size so that the first layout fills all the remaining space. Unfortunately, the first layouts now occupies all the space.

[image: Example image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/contact_background"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_padding"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="48sp"
        android:layout_height="48sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="48sp"
            android:layout_height="48sp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_circle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/online"
            android:layout_width="16sp"
            android:layout_height="16sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/avatar"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contactName"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:paddingEnd="16sp"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
                tools:text="Contact title"/>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_muted"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:alpha="0.75"
                android:contentDescription="@string/topic_muted"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:tint="@color/colorGray"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_notifications_off"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_blocked"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:alpha="0.75"
                android:contentDescription="@string/topic_blocked"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:tint="@color/colorGray"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_block"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_archived"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:alpha="0.75"
                android:contentDescription="@string/topic_archived"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:tint="@color/colorGray"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_filecab"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/contactPriv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxWidth="240sp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            tools:text="Contact private: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- This is what I added to achieve the result - start -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="38sp"
        android:layout_height="38sp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unreadCountt"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/pill_counter"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp"
            tools:text="9+" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- This is what I added to achieve the result - end -->
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd put all content into a `RelativeLayout` and then align everything like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/contact_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_padding">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/PersonIconHolder"
        android:layout_width="48sp"
        android:layout_height="48sp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="48sp"
            android:layout_height="48sp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_circle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/online"
            android:layout_width="16sp"
            android:layout_height="16sp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/avatar"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/unreadCountt"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/PersonIconHolder"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contactName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:paddingEnd="16sp"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
                tools:text="Contact title" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_muted"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:alpha="0.75"
                android:contentDescription="@string/topic_muted"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_notifications_off"
                app:tint="@color/colorGray" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_blocked"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:alpha="0.75"
                android:contentDescription="@string/topic_blocked"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_block"
                app:tint="@color/colorGray" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_archived"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:alpha="0.75"
                android:contentDescription="@string/topic_archived"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_filecab"
                app:tint="@color/colorGray" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactPriv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxWidth="240sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            tools:text="Contact private: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unreadCountt"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/pill_counter"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp"
        tools:text="9+" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to accomplish can be easily done by using [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout).

It reduces the complexity of your layout making it faster to load and re-load in case of being used in adapters. Using `ConstraintLayout` you also reduce XML size of your layout making it easier to edit (though, sometimes the difference is minimal).

There are many built-in features like constraint animations, guidelines and barriers for element positioning, automatic responsiveness using constraints etc.

The one downside - you have to add one more dependency to your project:

```
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0"
```

Here is the result you get:

[image: Result of the XML layout presented in this answer]

*I had to replace some colour, drawable and string resources to make this example work.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@color/lightGrayBackgroundColor"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/online"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="avatar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/avatar" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/icon_muted"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/avatar"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
        tools:text="Contact title example long long" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_muted"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:alpha="0.75"
        android:contentDescription="topic_muted"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/icon_blocked"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_done"
        app:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_blocked"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:alpha="0.75"
        android:contentDescription="topic_blocked"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/icon_archived"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_done"
        app:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_archived"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:alpha="0.75"
        android:contentDescription="topic_archived"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/unreadCountt"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_done"
        app:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactPriv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxWidth="240sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/unreadCountt"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/contactName"
        tools:text="Contact private: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unreadCountt"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/avatar"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp"
        tools:text="9+" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```